# Enabling c# 7 compilation in Project Rider

Tags: c#-7.0, rider

If I set the LangVersion to 7, I get the following error:

```
Error:CS1617: Invalid option '7' for /langversion;
must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6.
```

I can't install Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately for now it is not possible on mac/linux, but it is planned - around Q1 2017.

Source: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205987804-Rider-and-C-7-