# Is JetBrains Rider with C# 7.0 support on an USB-Drive possible?

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-7.0, rider

I´m trying to get a **C# 7.0 Solution** on an USB-Drive together because i don´t have Admin rights on all Computers where i am programming to install Visual Studio.

I now got Rider running on an USB-Drive.
The thing is, that i can only set the C# Version on 5.0 and I can´t install a newer Net.Framework (no Adminrights).

Is it somehow possible to give Rider some **portable MSBuildTools for C# 7.0**?
When it is possible, what do I need that Rider don´t mark me everything what is only supported from C# > 5.0 on compiling?

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830694/enabling-c-sharp-7-compilation-in-project-rider?rq=1

Comment: Why do you think that admin rights have anything to do with portable solutions? What do you mean by `Portable`? `Portable` means the library can be used from apps that target different platforms. You don't need a Portable library to create applications that don't require admin rights.

Comment: If by `Portable` you mean "just copy the folder", that's supported since 2002. Back then it was called `xcopy deployment`. Unless your application registers assemblies or tries perform restricted actions, you can just copy the contents of the `bin/release` folder and run it

Comment: @Mafii that's a very old question. It's no longer relevant. C# 7 support was added in 2017.1

Comment: @Liquidz are you asking how to make *Rider* "portable" ? This has nothing to do with the *languages* it supports. JDK has nothing to do with C# development. It's MSBuild and company that has to be copied into the USB. You *can* [download the MS Build tools separately](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017). Configuration is controlled by environment variables to allow side-by-side deployment of different VS versions. You may be able to install the Build tools on the USB stick, or just copy the folder and change the environment variables in the batch files

Comment: Actually you can download/build yourself msbuild from here https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild

Comment: And in Rider go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolsets and specify msbuild path to your msbuild.

Comment: Okey i downloaded the Buildtools and specified the path, but when i press Build Solution, he gives me the error: ".Net Framework 4.6.2 Not Installed" but i cant install this on the computer...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. You should put latest the MSBuild with Roslyn on the usb drive and select it in Settings on the Toolset and Build page.